# Typescript how to call and access dictionary keys from a loop

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary, javascript-objects

I have a dictionary like the one below

```
let dict = {
             a:{
                first:1, 
                second:2
               },
             b:{
                first:2, 
                second:3
               }
           }
```

I want to loop through the first set of keys and then manipulate the second set of keys. something like the below code:

```
    for(const firstKey of dict){
        firstKey.first = 5
    }
```

The problem is that compiler is giving me an error on `firstKey.first = 5`saying

```
Property 'first' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

Why is this happening? I also tried `firstKey[first]` which did not work either.

Answer (score 3):

The keys are not iterable. You need to use Object.keys() to get an array of keys to iterate, thusly:

```
for(const key of Object.keys(dict)) { 
   console.log(key, dict[key]);
}
```